# Creating Read-Only tagged Value in enterprise architect through c# add-ins

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise, enterprise-architect

I am currently working on add-in where I need to create read-only tag values  through code. 
The default way to add tagged values Element.TaggedValues.AddNew("Value", "")creates tagged values of type string only. 
I read that defining Type=Const creates read-only tagged values but when I tried Element.TaggedValues.AddNew("Value", "Const"),it creates tagged values of type string only. 
Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I read that defining Type=Const creates read-only tagged values"
Where did you get that information?

Comment: Also it would help if you provide the code you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 's a difference between adding a tagged value and adding a tagged value Definition.

To add a tagged value definition use something like

```
EA.PropertyType taggedValueType = EA.Repository.PropertyTypes.AddNew("myTagName","");
taggedValueType.Description = "some description";
taggedValueType.Detail = "Type=Const;"+Environment.Newline+"Default=Val;";
taggedValueType.Update();
```

Then add a tagged value of your type using

```
Element.TaggedValues.AddNew("myTagName","")
```

Comment: Does that really work for you? See my answer :-/ (I had not updated my browser and missed your answer)

Comment: Yes, you can define tagged values that way. I do it in one of my add-ins (EA Message Composer) In that add-in I even create RefGUID tagged values with 3 lines in the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Those predefined tagged values can only be created in the "Default Tagged Values" dialog and not individually. Once such a TV is created you can add it to your element via

```
tv = e.TaggedValues.AddNew("nameOfTheConstTV", "")
tv.Update()
```

I have not found a way to create such default TVs via the API. Once you try to supply multi-line details you just get empty details. Leaving away the line break also yields empty details. Scrappy EA :-( So you have to create them manually.

**Edit** It seems that the above constraint applies only when using scripting languages with the API.